# assigning attribute values in constructor or class, which is better?

Tags: java

Is there any difference between the following types of instantiation?
Whether I set the value directly where the variable is defined, or in the class constructor.

If not, what is best practice?

"In class":

```
class A {
    boolean b = true;

    public A(){
    }
}
```

"In constructor":

```
class B {
    boolean b;

    public B(){
        b = true;
    }
}
```

The variable type is just for the example.
The only difference I see is, when the attribute is a complex type (a class) which constructor depends on values that are given to the constructor of the containing class:

```
class A {
    B b;
    public A(String s){
        b = new B(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: all three cases depends on specific requirements, you can not use case 1, when you have requirements of case 2 or case 3. practice more and then you will your self get the answer, and believe me it would be awesome. :)

Comment: absolutely correct statement @user2320537.

Comment: There are [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually they both are equivalent. From a readability point of view, however, the first one is more readable. Also, it's easy to see the default value when someone navigates to the variable declaration from an IDE (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + mouse-click in Eclipse).

Check out what [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) has to say -

> This works well when the initialization value is available and the
>   initialization can be put on one line. However, this form of
>   initialization has limitations because of its simplicity. If
>   initialization requires some logic (for example, error handling or a
>   for loop to fill a complex array), simple assignment is inadequate.
>   Instance variables can be initialized in constructors, where error
>   handling or other logic can be used. To provide the same capability
>   for class variables, the Java programming language includes static
>   initialization blocks.

So you can easily use the simple one-liner initialization technique when the process is simple. For complex initialization choices, constructors are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign the value to variable in the class, then while creating instance of the class, directly your desired value will get assigned to the variable.

If you assign values in the constructor, then your variables will be first assigned a default value and then the values from constructors will get assigned.

Read on [initialization blocks, constructors and their order of execution](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/)

In case of best practice,

- If passing all the values to the costructor is must while creating the object, then construction initialization must be used.
- If there are some values which need to be default for every object, then you can assign outside constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Use an initialization block.  [Initializing Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

```
public class X {

  // The following is the initializer block
  {
  }

  public X() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but *why* are you recommending this?  Initializer blocks are an obscure and rarely used feature of Java.  It is not a good idea to use language features that is going to cause the reader to say "what the heck did did you do that for?".

Answer (score 1):

Both are almost same.

But an effective line from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

> . Instance variables can be initialized in constructors, where error handling or other logic can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables are assigned default values in case you don't assign one! Bu default boolean instance variables are assigned value false.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    boolean b;

    public void printData() {
        System.out.println("Defualt boolean value is " + b);
    }


   public static void main(String args[]) {
    HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
    hw.printData();
    }
}
```

and the output is `Defualt boolean value is false`.

Where are you assigning your variable is purely a design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Instance field initializations are copied to the start of the constructor by the compiler, so the first two approaches generate the exact same code (or pretty darn close).

(Note however that the above is not quite true for static field initializations vs the `static` initializer method.)

It's mainly a question of which seems clearer and less likely to lead to confusion/errors down the road.  And that depends on numerous factors, including personal style.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend C:

```
class C {
    private boolean b = true;

}
```

-> no (explicit) constructor -> less code -> easier to read